# Docker Python container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000 on Azure

Tags: azure, flask, docker-compose, containers, azure-container-registry

this container works perfectly locally, but when uploading it on azure this error occurs, I already set `WEBSITES_PORT=8000` env, and still getting this error:

> ERROR - Container menbeerdemo2021_0_fdd36c41 didn't respond to HTTP
> pings on port: 8000, failing site start.

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

EXPOSE 8000
ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  menbeer_web_backend:
    image: menbeerdemo2021.azurecr.io/menbeer-web-backend:latest
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.